# Cannot resolve collation conflict for replace operation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I am in the process of migrating some databases from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008.

I have one DB left to move. I have copied it to the 2008 to test.

But I am getting the following collation error when I try to run this query from the 2008 client back to the 2000 database

```
SELECT * 
FROM Ports.dbo.vwAppeals
```

gives

> Msg 446, Level 16, State 8, Line 1
>   Cannot resolve collation conflict for replace operation.

If I run the same query - from the 2008 client to the 2008 server i.e. on the copy that has been migrated - it returns the expected data without error.

It is a little slower than I would expect.

The `vwAppeals` object is a view, and I have checked the collation for every field on each of the underlying tables without finding anything other than <database default> in SQL Server 2000 Enterprise Manager. When I check in SQL Server Management Studio on the 2008 copy using this

```
SELECT
    col.name, col.id, col.xtype, col.collation 
FROM 
    Ports.dbo.syscolumns col
WHERE 
    id IN (SELECT [id]
           FROM [Ports].[dbo].[sysobjects]
           WHERE name = '<name_of_underlying_table>') 
    AND collation IS NOT NULL
```

all the collations are the same

Any idea what might be causing this error?

Comment: Look into this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Do you know if the error is definitely related to the view, i.e. does the view actually use the replace function?

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM Ports.dbo.vwAppeals WHERE 1 = 0` work, i.e. return an empty resultset? If so, then at least you know the error occurs during expression evaluation rather than some external process.

Comment: @Blam - thats suggesting that I should change the SQL2K DB to be SQL2008 compatible - but wouldn't that mean that SQL2K wouldn't be able to use it?

Comment: @RhysJones Yes - see below. It did use the replace function. I have replaced that now. _[sic]_ That query doesn't work. So the problem is in the view definition, or at least in how the 2 clients treat that view definition.

Comment: @Feargal It was comment "look into ..."

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there's not an underlying function that might be affecting this? Can you not rebuild the view incrementally to troubleshoot and identify the source of the conflict?

Comment: OK. So i have done this. There were a couple REPLACE() functions in there, that I have rewritten as UDFs using substring, charindex and patindex and now I get this: Msg 446, Level 16, State 8, Line 2
Cannot resolve collation conflict for substring operation. so I think I'm on the right line. But this only occurs when I am working FROM the 2008 client. I don't get the error when I'm working locally on the Win2K server. So it seems to be related to some difference between the to operating platforms.

Comment: So I have removed one of the UDFs and got rid of the associated calculated field. I can calculate it later if needed but actually it was to support a legacy product which we no longer support, so I think i won't need it anymore. But the problem still remains. i guess I need to remove the other UDF as a test.

Comment: OK. Found the culprit. The UDFs were actually fine. But there is a further substring calculated field - SUBSTRING(CAST(1000000 + ports.PIUID AS varchar(7)), 2, 6) AS UniqueIDString - whose function was to produce a 6 character zero-padded string representation of a smallint field PIUID. Thats what SQL Server 2008 is complaining about. Any suggestions as to why?